# variable undefined after replacing characters

Tags: jquery

I want to replace local characters typing in an input

```
var mapObj = {Č:"C", č:"c", Ć:"C", ć:"c", Đ:"D", đ:"d", Š:"S", š:"s", Ž:"Z", ž:"z"};

function clearlocale(x){
x = x.replace(/č|ć|đ|š|ž/i, function(matched) {
    return mapObj[matched];
});
}

$('#inpnew').keyup(function(e) {
    var a = $(this).val();
    console.log(a); //ok
    var b = clearlocale(a);
    console.log(b); // undefined
});
```

So why is `b` - `undefined` ?

Comment: Can you provide an example value for `a`?  Though in that method you are setting the value of x, and not returning it.  Indentation of nested logic might make that easier to see.

Comment: `clearLocale()` needs to return x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why is b - undefined ?

That's because `clearlocale` doesn't return anything. Return `x` after replacement is done.

```
function clearlocale(x){
  x = x.replace(/č|ć|đ|š|ž/i, function(matched) {
    return mapObj[matched];
  });
  return x;
}
```